# How to request user to authorize google service after OAuth signing in?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-authentication

I have an app having 2 personas: regular user and super users. For regular user, I just need to know their identify provided by Google (authentication). For super user, we need to access their Google Drive to store their information. Therefore, I need super users to authorize our app to allow us accessing their drive. And I know scope can be added in the OAuth sign in process to achieve this.

Edit: I am using Firebase Authentication in my app. By default, everyone will just be a regular user. Once they login, the user can opt-in to become super user, then our app will need to access their Google drive.

**Question**: Can I follow the same **authentication** process for both regular and super users, but then **only ask super user** to authorize our app using their drive after authentication is done? I don't want to add the OAuth scope to both types of users because regular user has no need for us to access to their drive.

Comment: Can you share more information such as how does your app identify if the user is a regular user? Or a super user?

Comment: @IrvinJayG. I am using Firebase Authentication in my app. By default, everyone will just be a regular user. Once they login, the user can opt-in to become super user.